# How to format table to something mobile friendly?

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile, mobile, html-table

I'm working on my first mobile version of a website. I have 1000s of articles which contain HTML tables in them. Unfortunately, they have fixed widths and have been used to layout content in some cases (mainly photo galleries).

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on ways to go through and format these tables so they display nicely on a mobile screen without the need of scrollbars? Like concerting to a list or a series of divs. Any ideas?

I'm using jQuery mobile as my framework and code in PHP.

The current only 'fix' I can think up is wrapping tables in a `<div>` with `width:100%` and `overflow-x:auto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively, you'd be breaking the table with css, but you could try something like this:

```
table{
  width: 100%;
}
tr{
  display: block;
}
td{
  float: left;
  width: 24%
}
```

That will make things act more like a bunch of divs than table rows and cells.
For actual tabular data, I really wouldn't recommend this. But for galleries and layouts you should be ok.